# Apache2 cookbook restarting apache in each chef-client run

Tags: apache, chef-infra, restart

I'm testing a basic [apache2](/questions/tagged/apache2)+[php](/questions/tagged/php) cookbook

```
include_recipe "apache2"
include_recipe "php"
include_recipe "apache2::mod_php5"

apache_site "default" do
  enable true
end
```

using also the chef-client recipe.

My problem is that every time that chef-client runs (at a certain interval), it restarts apache, I don't think it is the best approach.

Although I found something about setting the listen_ports as an attribute, it still restarts the service when finishing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please paste log output of your `chef-client` run (using `:info` severity (`-l info`)).

Comment: Yes, check out chef output, there will be written what triggers `service restart` action.

Comment: Please update your question to include the info output from the CCR (`sudo chef-client -l info`). Usually this happens when a template is being updated on each run, which notifies a restart.